# Make browser save file in certain location

Tags: java

Ok,I have a code to send a file as byte stream to the response.The browser downloads the file and save in default Download folder.Now i need to change that location through my code.How can i do that?Any ideas???????

```
File file = new File(SubsettedSavedPath);
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
response.setContentType("font/ttf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"Subsetter\"");
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

try {

os.write(buffer);
 response.addHeader("19.write","Completed"); 
os.flush();
 } catch (Exception excp) {
response.addHeader("exception", excp.getMessage());

excp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
os.close();
fis.close();
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't. That would be a major browser security issue, if you could write files anywhere you want

Comment: Which folder the downloaded files will be saved in is a setting of the browser. You can't possibly change that from your program

Comment: @StefanHaberl Maybe the OP is asking for advice on where to look for a major browser security issue? :3 But although telling the browser where to save is a flaw, I can't immediately see how *hinting* the browser to pop up the "choose save location" dialog with a chosen default is. (Still dodgy imho, but not directly abusable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change that through your code. Your code is on server side the borwser is a client program. Wouldn't it be scary, if websites could remote control your browser? The only thing you can do is, adding this to your response:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
```

The first line will set the type to "any-binary-type" (making sure the browser will not search for a plugin to open it internally, i.e. images or pdf), the second will mark it as an attachment. This will make sure the browser will open a save dialog, where your client can choose a path, and weather or not to save the file.

Comment: No, read my answer once more. Its about the specific content type "app./oct." and about the attachment option in content disposition.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You don't have access on the client's pc, it wouldn't be save.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an executable .exe, that on being run stores a payload in the corresponding directory.
The application will saved into a temp directory, and the user might chose to execute it. Scary.